# How to animate -webkit css properties with jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, webkit, jquery-animate

I want that by clicking on a button, the animation ( already set with css ) of my object goes faster.
No problem with firefox it work without problem, but I have trouble to make it work with chrome and webkit.

When I click I want the rotation to be 2s faster, so I use the function animate in my javascript and it works fine to change the `animation-duration` css property, but I don't know how to change the `-webkit-animation-duration` property,
so after changing the animation-duration, I basically copy it in the `webkit-animation-duration` with the css function.

The strangest thing is that it work, the alert at the end of the code display the right value. But the animation remain unchanged on the browser ( chrome ).

Once again, it works perfectly with firefox.

Javascript :

```
$("#eoleplus").click(function(){
    $flowers = $(".middleflower")
    $flowers.animate({animationDuration:'-=2s'});
    $flowerspeed=$flowers.css('animation-duration');
    $flower.css('-webkit-animation-duration',$flowerspeed);
    alert($flower.css('-webkit-animation-duration'));
});
```

CSS :

```
.middleflower {
    z-index:4;
    animation-name: rotate;
    animation-duration: 11s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 11s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```